# Why does the following regex not work for Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to delete a word and all its trailing whitespace.

Here is my regex:

`item.getName().replace(word + "(\\s*)?", "");`

I tested this statement by running:

`item.getName().replace(word, "");`

This executes successfully, albeit with extra whitespaces. So the error must be due to `"(\\s*)?"` part. Is it because I did not escape the slash correctly? Or does Java not recognize something in that regex?

Comment: Your string looks like a correct regex, but it's redundant. `*` matches 0 or more of a token, and `?` matches 0 or 1. So you are matching 0 or 1 groups of 0 or more spaces. Basically, it would do the same thing if you took out the `?`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) uses a `String` literal as its first argument. Use `replaceAll` instead

Comment: That works! Wow, I would have never figured that out.

Comment: You can also use [`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), too, if anything...

Answer (score 1):

String.replace method does not take regular expressions. I believe you'd have to use replaceAll in orer to use regular expression. Also, regular expressions are a general grammar that expresses a certain pattern of String rather than a particular instances that contain certain words. You can't mix a word with a regular expression such way.